# Need to run mvn clean install every time. Changes made in Eclipse are not reflected

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I need to run `mvn clean install` every time. Changes made in Eclipse are not reflected.

Build automatically is enabled and Eclipse is Neon.3

If I made some changes in Junit, to make that get reflected I need to manually do `mvn clean install` outside Eclipse and then run the Junit from Eclipse. It's like the class files are not getting generated from Eclipse.

Because of this I can't even run a standalone Java class and run it through Eclipse, it will show "Error: Could not find or load main class Test".

Any advice?

Comment: What happens if you run `clean install` from _within_ Eclipse?

Comment: Have you installed M2E integration? Have you imported the project correctly as Maven Projects? Apart from that what exactly do you mean by: `If i made some changes in junits and to make that get reflected..`? Do you mean changes at your unit tests? Have you run them from inside Eclipse?

Comment: I have installed Maven integration for eclipse (lune and newer) 1.5... I meant the changes i made to the junits are not reflected if i rerun from eclipse.. the changes will get reflected only if i do a mvn clean install outside and then run them from eclipse..

Comment: @JFMeier i tried project->clean, but it doesnt create new class files..

Comment: Right click on your project, "Run As -> Maven build.." and type "clean install" as goal. If you cannot see the options, then you need to convert you project to a Maven project first.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, right click on the project and do a Maven Update.

[Eclipse snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhSIC.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Maven instance is the same as used by Eclipse and double check the directory of the project is the same as the command line root dir you are using to fire Maven outside the IDE.
2. After you run `mvn clean install` (I presume from command line), right click on you Maven project in Eclipse, choose "Maven\Update Project" and flag "Force Update Snapshots/Releases" if necessary.
3. Check if your IDE has "Build Automatically" set. You can find it in the toolbar "Project" menu.

Let me know if that has helped you.